# Django Transaction Errors

Tags: django, transactions

I have a cronjob which processes emails and stores them in the system. It'd been working well for over a year but now all of a sudden it has started giving these weird transaction errors randomly every now and then.

```
2010-09-02-01:45:11 ERROR Exception occured during mail processing
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/example.com/project/scripts/cronjobs.py", line 453, in process_msg
   source, email, 'i' if rejection_reason else 'v', rejection_reason)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 267, in _commit_manually
   leave_transaction_management()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 77, in leave_transaction_management
   raise TransactionManagementError("Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK")
TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

It happens without any reason and there isn't any other context information available to me. Here is the structure of my process_msg function:

```
@commit_manually
def save_email( u,l, d, t, s, e, status, reason):
    try:
        # ... bla bla bla ... 
        commit()
    exception, e:
        rollback()
        raise e

def process_msg(m):
    try:
        #....
        save_email(u, l, d, t
            source, email, 'i' if rejection_reason else 'v', rejection_reason)
        #....
     except Exception, e:
        logger.error('Error while processing email', exc_info=True )
        return None
    else:
        return True
```

How how I probe this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the error occurred before entering `save_email()`. With no `commit()` or `rollback()` directive in `process_msg()` a TransactionError is raised.

You could try to circle the error with a debugger:

```
def process_msg(m):
    try:
        import pdb                    # import python debugger
        pdb.set_trace()               # begin debugging
        #....
        save_email(u, l, d, t,
        […]
```

You can find information on how to use the debugger on the [Python website](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html).

Comment: Using debugger is not an option. Its a cronjob which triggers it and error appears randomly